# Magento 2 : main.CRITICAL: A valid response status line was not found

Tags: magento2, error-log, system.log

Everytime I get issue in system.log

```
[2018-09-10 09:35:52] main.CRITICAL: A valid response status line was not found in the provided string {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Http: http://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_19418(,|$))|((^|,)cat_p_19420(,|$))"}} []
[2018-09-10 09:35:52] main.CRITICAL: A valid response status line was not found in the provided string {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Http: http://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_19419(,|$))|((^|,)cat_p_19420(,|$))"}} []
[2018-09-10 09:35:52] main.CRITICAL: A valid response status line was not found in the provided string {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Http: http://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_19420(,|$))"}} []
```

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

These requests suppose to clean the varnish cache by tag pattern. According to the log entries, you have something wrong with varnish configurations. 
You can find configuration details here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html.

Comment: I took the time to do some research and also pointed the finger towards custom caching and got a negative score for my answer. Be interested to see what response you get here.